# How do you left-align text to the center of multiple, vertically-stacked divs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, centering

I have the below snippet, demonstrating vertically-stacked divs containing spans of text:

```css
.WBG {
    background-color: #e6e6e6 !important;
}
.mt-buffer-lg {
    margin-top: 20pt;
}
.tb-border {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #bfbfbf;
}
.pad-sm {
    padding: 5pt;
}
.tb-border-top {
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-color: #bfbfbf;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row mt-buffer-lg">
      <div class="col-12">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <div class="WBG tb-border">
                      <div class="pad-sm text-center">
                          <span>123456789</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="tb-border-top pad-sm text-center">
                          <span>1234567</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="tb-border-top pad-sm text-center">
                          <span>123456</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="tb-border-top pad-sm text-center">
                          <span>1234</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="tb-border-top pad-sm text-center">
                          <span>1234</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <div class="WBG tb-border pad-sm">
                      2
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example of what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lcXd.png)

This shows that text is all aligned on the first character of each string of numbers but is still 'in the middle' of each div - horizontally. How would this best be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricking but the big insight here is you need to set display:inline-block to your .WBG and set display:block to your spans

```css
.WBG {
    background-color: #e6e6e6 !important;
    display:inline-block;
}
.mt-buffer-lg {
    margin-top: 20pt;
}
.tb-border {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #bfbfbf;
}
.pad-sm {
    padding: 5pt;
}
.tb-border-top {
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-color: #bfbfbf;
}

span{
display:block;
text-align:left;}

.col-sm-2{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row mt-buffer-lg">
      <div class="col-12">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <div class="WBG tb-border">
                      <div class="pad-sm text-center">
                          <span>123456789</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="tb-border-top pad-sm text-center">
                          <span>1234567</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="tb-border-top pad-sm text-center">
                          <span>123456</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="tb-border-top pad-sm text-center">
                          <span>1234</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="tb-border-top pad-sm text-center">
                          <span>1234</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't really seem to work as it collapses the width of the stacked-divs to the size of the biggest span of text, and then when you re-size them in css it just left aligns the text by default? I still want there to be white-space either side of the text with the div widths unchanged but just aligning text by the first char

Comment: see answer below, does that solve your problem?  If not please explain

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricking but the big insight here is you need to set display:inline-block to your .WBG and set display:block to your spans

If you want to center everything you need to over ride bootstrap

```css
.WBG {
    background-color: #e6e6e6 !important;
    display:inline-block;
}
.mt-buffer-lg {
    margin-top: 20pt;
}
.tb-border {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #bfbfbf;
}
.pad-sm {
    padding: 5pt;
}
.tb-border-top {
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-color: #bfbfbf;
}

span{
display:block;
text-align:left;}

.col-sm-2{
text-align:center;
}

@media (min-width: 576px){
.col-sm-2 {
        max-width:100%!important;
        flex:none!important;
        }
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row mt-buffer-lg">
      <div class="col-12">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <div class="WBG tb-border">
                      <div class="pad-sm text-center">
                          <span>123456789</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="tb-border-top pad-sm text-center">
                          <span>1234567</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="tb-border-top pad-sm text-center">
                          <span>123456</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="tb-border-top pad-sm text-center">
                          <span>1234</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="tb-border-top pad-sm text-center">
                          <span>1234</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work either because I get [this](https://imgur.com/a/m1AzxXz) but I want [this](https://imgur.com/a/134yEan)